Using two unrelated tables in a Deneb Visual in Power BI
I've looked at this page https://deneb-viz.github.io/dataset. I can't figure out how to use two (or more) unrelated tables in a Deneb visual in Power BI.
From this example https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/timelines/ I'm trying to map people and events Power BI table to dataset somehow.
When I add columns from both tables, the visual gives me the "Can't determine relationships between the fields" error.

You need to union (append) the separate tables in Power Query and then manually split them in Deneb. There is an example on my page here: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase?tab=readme-ov-file#force-direct-graph-dynamic
Nodes and links are two separate datasets which are appended and then split in the spec.
